# ¿Como autocompletar label de acuerdo a un dato en textbox?

Tags: c#, asp.net

lo que necesito es que cuando un usuario escriba un codigo en un textbox, "aparezca" el nombre relacionado a ese codigo en un label.

En el evento click de mi botón guardar intente con este código pero no lo hace, sino hasta que finaliza todo el proceso de guardar. Y lo que yo necesito es que lo muestre y luego lo guarde.

```
 //Agregar el nuevo codigo
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Insert into tabla1 (...) VALUES(@cod...)", con);
cmd.Parameters.Add("@cod", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = codigo.Text;
.
.
.
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

//aqui busco el nombre relacionado al codigo ingresado
SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand("Select Nombre from tabla2 where Cod='" + codigo.Text + "'", con);
cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();
label3.Text = Convert.ToString(cmd2.ExecuteScalar());
Thread.Sleep(10000);
```

Gracias por leer.

Comment: Autocomplete con Jquery, dale una revisada a esto: https://www.devbridge.com/sourcery/components/jquery-autocomplete/

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/77248/discussion-between-gbianchi-and-mengana).

Answer (score 0):

Tan solo debes hacer el `select` antes del `insert`, puedes ejecutar el `select` y dormir el codigo y luego se ejecutara el `insert`.

```
SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand("Select Nombre from tabla2 where Cod='" + codigo.Text + "'", con);
cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();
label3.Text = Convert.ToString(cmd2.ExecuteScalar());
Thread.Sleep(10000);

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Insert into tabla1 (...) VALUES(@cod...)", con);
cmd.Parameters.Add("@cod", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = codigo.Text;
.
.
.
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Aunque no recomiendo la estructura que llevas debes pensar en agregar otro boton al menos uno pequeño al lado del textbox y que ese ejecute tu consulta select, de esa manera el usuario controla si quiere utilizar ese codigo o no.